# Problem in Automatically log into Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, login, windows-authentication, windows-server

I could not automatically logged into sharepoint site with the window user account. I have to click "SignIn" button displayed on the right of the screen.(as shown in picture)
[image]

As described in this link ( http://blogs.kma-llc.net/microknowledge/2011/03/configuring-internet-explorer-for-automatic-sharepoint-login.html), I configured Internet explorere settings by:

```
1.  add site url in local intranet 
2. and set user authentication to "Automatic logon with current user name and password"
```

But I still get this SignIn button instead of my window user id.

Do I need to do any configuration at Central Administrator?

Comment: What authentication mode and provider are you using?  Is the site configured for anonymous access?

Comment: Yes, Anonymous access is enabled, is that causing problem?

Comment: @RohitaKhatiwada is your server is in development environment and what you actually trying to achieve ? do you want to give everyone access to the site without login or you just want it for yourself on your machine only ?

Comment: Yes, Currently I am working in a development server.But in future we are going to use production server so that all external users can access our site. Therefore I need to enable annymous user to let them access our site without requiring them to login.

Comment: Can you confirm, if you followed all of steps in this article, http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I found that , the purpose of anonymous user is to allow external users without having required to signin. Therefore instead of user id, signIn was displayed on the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to do any configuration at Central Administrator?

If you want it just for your personal machine then you shouldn't touch CA.

You need to perform some additional steps, e.g. creating a group policy and modifying IE Enhanced Security Configuration.

Follow this article out,

[How do I make our SharePoint site stop asking me to login? – Part I](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/how-do-i-make-our-sharepoint-site-stop.html)

[How do I make our SharePoint site stop asking me to login? – Part II](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/how-do-i-make-our-sharepoint-site-stop_17.html)

**Update**

Since you want anonymous access for all user's follow this post but just to let you know you will need to make changes to Web Application through CA,

[Enable Anonymous Access in SharePoint 2010](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're logging in with URL that is being configured for Internet (alternate access mapping) aka anonymous access. Can you check if the URL is correct? Are you extending the Web application for anonymous access?

Comment: Url is correct. But  Annonymous accesss is enabled.  Is that causing problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also if this is a local machine, you might have to add your machine  to the local intranet sites so that Windows Authentication works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be an anonymous site it will not auto log you in.  I was able to "fix" this by using some custom code.  My solution is outlined on my blog here:  http://steve.thelineberrys.com/ntlm-login-with-anonymous-fallback-2/